# Activity return itself to previous activity without clicking back button

Tags: android, android-activity

My Previous activity is:

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityMenuList extends Activity {

    ListView listMenu;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    //TextView txtTitle;
    EditText edtKeyword;
    ImageButton btnSearch;
    TextView txtAlert;

    // declare static variable to store tax and currency symbol
    static double Tax;
    static String Currency;

    // declare adapter object to create custom menu list
    AdapterMenuList mla;

    // create arraylist variables to store data from server
    static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Double> Menu_price = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<String> Menu_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    String MenuAPI;
    String TaxCurrencyAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;
    long Category_ID;
    String Category_name;
    String Keyword;

    // create price format
    DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setTitle("Product");
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        listMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
        edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);
        btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        // menu API url
        MenuAPI = Constant.MenuAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&category_id=";
        // tax and currency API url
        TaxCurrencyAPI = Constant.TaxCurrencyAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;

        // get category id and category name that sent from previous page
        Intent iGet = getIntent();
        Category_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id",0);
        Category_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");
        MenuAPI += Category_ID;

        // set category name to textview
//        txtTitle.setText(Category_name);

        mla = new AdapterMenuList(ActivityMenuList.this);

        // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
        new getTaxCurrency().execute();

        // event listener to handle search button when clicked
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // get keyword and send it to server
                try {
                    Keyword = URLEncoder.encode(edtKeyword.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MenuAPI += "&keyword="+Keyword;
                IOConnect = 0;
                listMenu.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

        // event listener to handle list when clicked
        listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // go to menu detail page
                Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityMenuDetail.class);
                iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
                startActivity(iDetail);
                //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);

//      final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
//     

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cart:
                // refresh action
                Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityCart.class);
                startActivity(iMyOrder);
                overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            case R.id.refresh:
                IOConnect = 0;
                listMenu.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getTaxCurrency(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONDataTax();
            return null;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if internet connection and data available request menu data from server
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Currency != null) && IOConnect == 0){
            new getDataTask().execute();
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONDataTax(){
    try {
        // request data from tax and currency API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

        JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Currency = currency.getString("Value");


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        IOConnect = 1;
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData(){
    Menu_ID.clear();
    Menu_name.clear();
    Menu_price.clear();
    Menu_image.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

        // if data available show data on list
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if(Menu_ID.size() > 0){
            listMenu.setVisibility(0);
            listMenu.setAdapter(mla);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }

    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONData(){

    clearData();

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

            Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
            Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
            Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
            Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));

        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    listMenu.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}
```

}

The activity which get crashed is as:

```
public class ActivityMenuDetail extends Activity {

    ImageView imgPreview;
    TextView txtText, txtSubText;
    WebView txtDescription;
    Button btnAdd;
    ScrollView sclDetail;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    TextView txtAlert;

    // declare dbhelper object
    static DBHelper dbhelper;

    // declare ImageLoader object
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    // declare variables to store menu data
    String Menu_image, Menu_name, Menu_serve, Menu_description;
    double Menu_price;
    int Menu_quantity;
    long Menu_ID;
    String MenuDetailAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;

    // create price format
    DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_detail);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setTitle("Detail Menu");
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        txtSubText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
        txtDescription = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        //btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        sclDetail = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sclDetail);
        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        // get screen device width and height
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int wPix = dm.widthPixels;
        int hPix = wPix / 2 + 50;


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPix, hPix);
        imgPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ActivityMenuDetail.this);
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

        // get menu id that sent from previous page
        Intent iGet= super.getIntent();
        Menu_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("menu_id", 0);

        // Menu detail API url
        MenuDetailAPI = Constant.MenuDetailAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&menu_id="+Menu_ID;


        new getDataTask().execute();


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // show input dialog
                inputDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cart:
                // refresh action
                Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuDetail.this, ActivityCart.class);
                startActivity(iMyOrder);
                overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:

                this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    void inputDialog(){


        try{
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle(R.string.order);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.number_order);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        final EditText edtQuantity = new EditText(this);
        int maxLength = 3;
        edtQuantity.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
        edtQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        alert.setView(edtQuantity);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String temp = edtQuantity.getText().toString();
                int quantity = 0;

                // when add button clicked add menu to order table in database
                if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                        dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                    }else{
                        dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                    }
                }else{
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                // when cancel button clicked close dialog
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            // if internet connection and data available show data
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if((Menu_name != null) && IOConnect == 0){
                sclDetail.setVisibility(0);

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+Menu_image, imgPreview);

                txtText.setText(Menu_name);
                txtSubText.setText("Price : " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList.Currency+"\n"+"Status : "+Menu_serve+"\n"+"Stock : "+Menu_quantity);
                txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                txtDescription.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        try {
            // request data from menu detail API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuDetailAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu_detail");

                Menu_image = menu.getString("Menu_image");
                Menu_name = menu.getString("Menu_name");
                Menu_price = Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price")));
                Menu_serve = menu.getString("Serve_for");
                Menu_description = menu.getString("Description");
                Menu_quantity = menu.getInt("Quantity");

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IOConnect = 1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // close database before back to previous page
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        dbhelper.close();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //imageLoader.clearCache();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

My LogCat is:

> 12-08 12:38:56.878 27269-27269/? E/DevelopmentSettings: IO Exception
>   when getting meta version for Device Info screen
>                                                           java.io.FileNotFoundException: /firmware/verinfo/ver_info.txt: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103)
>                                                               at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66)
>                                                               at com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings.readLine(DevelopmentSettings.java:433)
>                                                               at com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings.onCreate(DevelopmentSettings.java:315)
>                                                               at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483)
>                                                               at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.switchToFragment(SettingsActivity.java:999)
>                                                               at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:625)
>                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6001)
>                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
>                                                            Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>                                                               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76) 
>                                                               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:103) 
>                                                               at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:66) 
>                                                               at com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings.readLine(DevelopmentSettings.java:433) 
>                                                               at com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings.onCreate(DevelopmentSettings.java:315) 
>                                                               at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031) 
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863) 
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833) 
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452) 
>                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483) 
>                                                               at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.switchToFragment(SettingsActivity.java:999) 
>                                                               at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:625) 
>                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6001) 
>                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                               at

Comment: do you have any error log in logcat?

Comment: yes...12-06 15:27:53.691 848-863/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.settings.applications.SpProvider.....12-06 15:26:31.345 19445-19445/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 71 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.google.android.calendar/databases/timelydata.db-wal

Comment: paste your complete logcat

Comment: @MeghaJain can u debug and check whether there is value in extras you are using and also is there any issue in asyntask?

Comment: paste your logcat

Comment: kindly paste the whole logcat.

Comment: @MeghaJain that's not your complete logcat

Comment: You should not filter the logcat. You may be losing valuable information.

Comment: @DavidWasser: I cant paste the total logcat here. thats why i filtered it.. If you can tell how to paste logcat here then i will paste it here

Comment: @Megha Jain you can edit your question and paste your logcat

Comment: i cant post it there because it is too big to paste there

Comment: Don't post the logcat as a comment. Just edit your question and put it in there. If it is too big to put in the question, then you need to trim the logcat down to the relevant parts. Don't past 200MB of crap from your phone that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser: I have added logcat

Comment: It doesn't look like this logcat has anything to do with your application. It doesn't looks like you are using fragments. Are you running on an emulator or on a real device. What device? What version of Android are you running?

Comment: Android 5.0. Yes  i am running on the real device...